# Python database fields clashing

Tags: python, database

I am trying to define multiple database fields in one line as the values are the same. I have tried:

```
a = b = c = d = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

and

```
a, b, c, d = (models.CharField(max_length=100),)*4
```

but I get an error saying `The field 'a' clashes with the field 'a' from model 'database'.`. Is this not possible for database field models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a = b = c = X` assigns the *same* `X` object to `a`, `b`, and `c`, making them aliases of each other:

```
a = b = [1, 2]
b.append(3)
assert a == [1, 2, 3]
```

The `*` for lists / tuples is a shortcut for using the same object multiple times. It's fine with immutable objects like numbers, but has the same problem with mutable things that should eventually differ:

```
a = ([1, 2],) * 2
a[0].append(5)
assert a = ([1, 2, 5], [1, 2, 5])
```

If you want three separate fields, create them three times.

If you find yourself copy-pasting the same thing several times, use a loop, or a list comprehension:

```
a, b, c = [models.CharField(...) for _ in range(3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bad idea. Could be hard to debug in the future. Though if you do want it then this is how tuple unpacking works `a, b, c = 'A', 'B', 'C'`.

So for your case it will be

```
a, b, c, d = models.CharField(max_length=100), models.CharField(max_length=100), models.CharField(max_length=100), models.CharField(max_length=100)
```